# Why can't init'd Python process see other processes?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a Python process that runs on my system and checks to see if other processes are running.  I have a problem where on reboot, my Python does not work.  I assume it has something to do with the the environment at boot.  If I stop my Python script (from boot) and start it as root or as a user of "dataturbine", it works fine. Here is the interesting portion of the init script:

```
SERVER_HOST=`hostname`
SERVER_PORT='3333'
RBNB_LOG_DIR=/var/log/rbnb
LOG_FILE="${RBNB_LOG_DIR}/dataturbine-rpc.log"
DT_USER=dataturbine
OWNER=${DT_USER}:${DT_USER}
RBNB_RUN_DIR=/var/run/rbnb
PIDFILE=${RBNB_RUN_DIR}/dataturbine-rpc.pid
SCRIPT=/usr/local/rbnb/scripts/dataturbine.py

######################################################################################
start() {
if [ ${USER} == ${DT_USER} ]
   then
     ${SCRIPT} -logfile ${LOG_FILE} -bindport 12000 -bindip 0.0.0.0 > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > ${PIDFILE}
   else
     su -m -c "${SCRIPT} -logfile ${LOG_FILE} -bindport 12000 -bindip 0.0.0.0  > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$"'!'" > ${PIDFILE}" ${DT_USER}
   fi
}
```

Here is the Python command that gets run to check for a running process.  It comes back with a 0 from the "WC" command on init, even though the process is running:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("/bin/ps -ef | /bin/grep 'DaqToRbnb' | /bin/grep -v grep | /usr/bin/wc -l", shell=True)
```

Comment: What's in the output when you skip the grepping? I'm sure all other processes are already visible, but maybe what you're looking for really isn't there yet? Try without grep so your question changes from "why can't I see other processes", to either "why ps doesn't work" (when do you run it? is /proc already mounted?), or "why can't I see that specific process" (why isn't it running yet?) - also remember to capture the stderr too, not just stdout

Comment: My Python process runs in a loop.  It never sees other processes if run from init.

Comment: On another note, most likely, `grep 'DaqToRbnb' | grep -v grep | wc -l` can be reduced to `grep -c '[D]aqToRbnb'`...

Comment: Very good point anishsane.

Comment: @mikeboldischar still - what *does* it see? It cannot see a different process list (unless you're running with a gr-sec kernel, specific selinux/apparmor profile, or something similar) so what's the output or error of ps?

Comment: I'll be able to do some more testing on the system in a week.  The first thing I'll do is see what other processes are listed.  I'll have to read more about the security on Debian.